# Polygons and colors do not appear in qgis2web export

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have been trying to export a map from QGIS using the qgis2web plugin. But my polygons and classification colors are not displayed in the exported HTML file, I only can see the Google Street Map layer.

My map has a layer for Google Street Map and another with polygons from a shapefile, colored based on one of the columns from a CSV file.

Here's the map:
[image]

When I try to export the map (I tried OpenLayers and Leaflet), the preview is what I expect:
[image]

but the final HTML file only displays the Google Street Map layer. Not the polygons/colors.

[image]

Any thoughts on why is that happening?

EDIT:
Included the 'appearance tab'
[image]

Comment: Hello. Normally this should be not a problem for qgis2web. I have never tested the variant with colored from a csv file. Maybe this is the reason. Any problems if you take the colores from the categorized shapefile? Which qgis/qgis2web version?(for windows?)

Comment: Same problems, if you export only your shapefile?

Comment: I've tried to export only the shapefiles, but the output is an empty map...
I'm using:  QGIS: 3.14.15-Pi and qgis2web: 3.16

Comment: I'm installing the previous version of QGIS, and if that doesn't work I'll try another OS (currently on windows)

Comment: Could you take a screenshot from "Appearance"? (edit your question)

Comment: done! the tests I tried all failed :/

Comment: Unfortunately I can not see a mistake. Hmm. It is possible to share ( a part of) your polygon layer? Only for testing.

Comment: of course! they are public, comes from the government website, this is one part: https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios_shp/mt/mt_setores_censitarios.zip

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem with the shapefile. My System: QGIS 3.10.10, qgis2web 3.16 on Windows 10.

Comment: I also managed to create the map for this shapefile alone, I'll include de classification for this one, to check if the csv is the problem

Comment: The map works for this smaller shapefile, including the classifications from the CSV. Probably the map I was trying to load is too heavy for the extension.

Comment: Maybe. Try: qgis2web - export - minify geojson files: check - precision: "6"

Comment: Just keep in mind that QGIS rendering and web rendering two completely different things. So qgis2web tries to "translate"/convert from one logic to the other one. This works reasonably well, but not 100%. In my experience, standard symbology without any changes have larger change to get rendered in the web output than if you manually adapt the style in QGIS. So probably best is indeed to use standard data source and try to export the layer with just a simple standard style to see if that works. Final tweak for style should be done in the output.

Answer (score 1):

My teammate and I had this exact issue. It turned out to be because the attribute name used for the color classification was case-sensitive in qgis2web.